# Cobol z/OS: how to determine calling parameters in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, cobol, zos

for z/OS Cobol the linkage-section defines data structures that can be shared with other programs.

What I wanted to ask: when I am debugging a cobol program with the z/OS debugger is there a way to show the variables and their content which have been passed to the program?
In other words: the calling program has called a sub-program using the "by reference" or "by content" qualifiers. Is there a way to show these data strcutures in the called program in the debugger?

thanks!

Comment: Can't you inspect the caller's state, too? In this case just switch to the caller and directly have a look at that?

Comment: @SimonSobisch: I don't know a way to switch to the caller dynamically.  I could start debugging in the caller and when the sub-program is called look at the passed data structures. Its just that in a long calling chain I often found myself in a situation in a sub-program where it would be helpful to show the calling variables + content. I am sure the debugger "knows" but I know of no way to extract that information ad hoc .... thanks!

Comment: Which interface do you use for debugging? The 3270 MFI or the eclipse-based remote-debugger?

Comment: @piet.t  I am directly on the host, using a TSO session and then I call "dtcn" to activate the debugger

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: since at the moment I don't have a COBOL environment for testing my description was tested using PL/I programs. COBOL should be working similar but could need some small corrections. Feel free to edit in anything you notice.

While it is easier in the GUI-Interface (as easy as clicking the correct entry in the callstack) you can switch to programs higher in the call hierarchy on the mainframe debug interface as well using the .

Assume you have a main program MYPROG calling a subprogram SUBPROG. After the debugger stopped somewhere in SUBPROG you can use the command

```
SET QUALIFY BLOCK MYPROG
```

to switch your debugging context to the main program. There you should be able to list any variables that are active in MYPROG at that moment.
With COBOL you could also try using

```
SET QUALIFY RETURN
```

to move up 1 level on the callstack or

```
SET QUALIFY PROGRAM MYPROG
```

which both don't work on PL/I (they end up one qualification level above the required BLOCK).

To return to your current debugging position issue the command

```
SET QUALIFY RESET
```

Since you mentioned DTCN I assume you are running in a CICS environment. This might add additional complications: the context-switching described above will only work across COBOL `CALL`-statements, not across `EXEC CICS LINK`. The latter will create a totally new Language Environment enclave so from the view of LE (and thus the debugger) there are two totally independent main program invocations.

Comment: Great set of commands, I am just beginning to understand their full potenzial!

Answer (score 1):

In the called COBOL program, you can also issue the `LIST TITLED LS` command to display the values of all variables in the `LINKAGE SECTION`.  Here's a simple example:

```
LIST TITLED LS ;                                           
The following variables are known in section Linkage Section
01 IBCC20A:>THIS-DATE  = 20280515
```

Comment: very useful thanks! - it seems to work for other namend sections, e.g. list titled WS